# How to draw a "proper" tree diagram

Tags: graphics, output-formatting, labeling, trees

```
TreePlot[{
    {0 -> "Mr 1", 1/10},
    {0 -> "Mr 2", 2/10},
    {0 -> "Mr 3", 3/10},
    {0 -> "Mr 4", 4/10},
    {"Mr 1" -> "A1",  2/10 },
    {"Mr 1" -> "B1",  1/10 },
    {"Mr 1" -> "C1",  7/10 },
    {"Mr 2" -> "A2",  3/10 },
    {"Mr 2" -> "B2",  2/10 },
    {"Mr 2" -> "C2",  5/10 },
    {"Mr 3" -> "A3",  4/10 },
    {"Mr 3" -> "B3",  3/10 },
    {"Mr 3" -> "C3",  3/10 },
    {"Mr 4" -> "A4",  5/10 },
    {"Mr 4" -> "B4",  4/10 },
    {"Mr 4" -> "C4",  1/10 }
}, 
VertexLabels ->
    {
        {0 -> None},
        { "A1" -> "A" },
        { "B1" -> "B" },
        { "C1" -> "C" },
        { "A2" -> "A" },
        { "B2" -> "B" },
        { "C2" -> "C" },
        { "A3" -> "A" },
        { "B3" -> "B" },
        { "C3" -> "C" },
        { "A4" -> "A" },
        { "B4" -> "B" },
        { "C4" -> "C" }
    },
    DirectedEdges -> True
]
```

Here is what I have. However, that's far from what I need.

[image]
[image]

A few modifications are:
1 - to put it horizontally?
2 - Why aren't the labels showing?
3 - Could I increase the spaces between the edges so that the probabilities are displayed better?

Thanks.

Comment: Would be great if wolfram added a super function on top of Graph for decision trees of this sort since this is a common use case in business.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We can use `TreePlot`  (`` GraphComputation`TreePlotLegacy `` in versions 12.0+) with the *hidden* option `"VertexNames"` to label vertices with arbitrary labels.

We need a function to post-process `TreePlot` output to fix the default orientation of edge labels:

```
ClearAll[modifyArrowheads]
modifyArrowheads[dir_: Automatic] := ReplaceAll[Inset[a_, b__, None, c___] :> 
    Inset[Framed[a, Background -> White, FrameStyle -> None], b, dir,   c]];
```

***Examples:***

```
labelingrules = {0 -> None, "A1" -> "A", "B1" -> "B", "C1" -> "C", "A2" -> "A", 
  "B2" -> "B", "C2" -> "C", "A3" -> "A", "B3" -> "B", "C3" -> "C", 
  "A4" -> "A", "B4" -> "B", "C4" -> "C"};

vlabels = VertexList[edges[[All, 1]]] /. labelingrules /. None -> "    ";

tp = TreePlot[MapAt[InputForm, edges, {All, -1}], Left, 
  VertexLabeling -> True, "VertexNames" -> vlabels, 
  DirectedEdges -> True, BaseStyle -> "FontSize" -> 12, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> Large];

modifyArrowheads[] @ tp
```

[image]

To have the edge labels appear horizontal regardless of edge orientation use

```
modifyArrowheads[{None, None}] @ tp
```

[image]

We can use the (also hidden) options `"VertexFrameStyle"`, `"VertexFrameBackground"` and `"VertexTextStyle"` to get a result similar to the hand-drawn picture in OP:

```
tp2 = TreePlot[MapAt[InputForm, edges, {All, -1}], Left, 
   VertexLabeling -> True, DirectedEdges -> True, 
   BaseStyle -> "FontSize" -> 12, AspectRatio -> 1, 
   ImageSize -> Large, "VertexNames" -> vlabels, 
   "VertexFrameStyle" -> None, "VertexFrameBackground" -> White, 
   "VertexTextStyle" -> {"Subsection", "FontColor" -> Blue}];

modifyArrowheads[] @ tp2
```

[image]

**Aside:** Re: *"why are the ABC in decending order?  Is there a way to work around for this minor anti-common practice?"*

We can use an additional post-processing step to flip the graphics output vertically:

```
ClearAll[vFlipCoords]
vFlipCoords = ReplaceAll[GraphicsComplex[pts_, prims___] :> 
    GraphicsComplex[ReflectionTransform[{0, -1}]@pts, prims]];

vFlipCoords @ modifyArrowheads[] @ tp2
```

[image]

#### Full list of hidden options for `TreePlot`:

```
Network`GraphPlotDump`Private`hiddenOptions[TreePlot]
```

> ```
>  {"VertexTooltips" -> Automatic, "EdgeTooltips" -> Automatic, 
>  "EdgeLabels" -> Automatic, "VertexNames" -> Automatic, 
>  "VertexSizes" -> Automatic, "VertexColor" -> Automatic, 
>  "EdgeColor" -> Automatic, "VertexFrameBackground" -> Automatic, 
>  "VertexFrameStyle" -> Automatic, "VertexFrameMargins" -> Automatic, 
>  "VertexTextStyle" -> True, "Plot" -> True}
> ```

**Note:** We need the post-processing to 1/ add white background to edge labels and 2/ to ensure proper orientation of edge labels.

Comment: Why are the ABC in `decending order` here, same as the other answer. Is there a way to work around for this minor `anti` common practice ?

Comment: @CasperYC, please see the update.

Comment: Sorry about the late response. SE is extremely difficult to acccess in China. Thanks again!

Answer (score 21):

It's a fussy solution, but it works.

```
edges = {{0 -> "Mr 1", 1/10}, {0 -> "Mr 2", 2/10}, {0 -> "Mr 3", 
    3/10}, {0 -> "Mr 4", 4/10}, {"Mr 1" -> "A1", 
    2/10}, {"Mr 1" -> "B1", 1/10}, {"Mr 1" -> "C1", 
    7/10}, {"Mr 2" -> "A2", 3/10}, {"Mr 2" -> "B2", 
    2/10}, {"Mr 2" -> "C2", 5/10}, {"Mr 3" -> "A3", 
    4/10}, {"Mr 3" -> "B3", 3/10}, {"Mr 3" -> "C3", 
    3/10}, {"Mr 4" -> "A4", 5/10}, {"Mr 4" -> "B4", 
    4/10}, {"Mr 4" -> "C4", 1/10}};

labels = {"A1" -> "A", "B1" -> "B", "C1" -> "C", "A2" -> "A", 
   "B2" -> "B", "C2" -> "C", "A3" -> "A", "B3" -> "B", "C3" -> "C", 
   "A4" -> "A", "B4" -> "B", "C4" -> "C"};
```

```
g = Graph[
 edges[[All, 1]],
 EdgeLabels -> Map[First[#] -> Placed[Framed[InputForm@Last[#], FrameStyle -> None, FrameMargins -> 1], {.7 (* position along edge *), {.5, 0.6} (* relative position within label *) }] &, edges],
 EdgeLabelStyle -> Directive[10 (* font size *), Background -> White],
 VertexLabels -> Flatten[{Placed["Name", Center] (* default label *), 0 -> None, MapAt[Placed[#, Center] &, labels, {All, 2}]}],
 VertexSize -> 0.7,
 GraphStyle -> "DiagramGold",
 GraphLayout -> {"LayeredEmbedding", "Orientation" -> Left, LayerSizeFunction -> (5 &)}
]
```

[image]

---

From the comments:

> A minor question, why are the ABC in decending order?

You can extract the vertex coordinates, flip them vertically, and set them on the graph again.

```
Graph[g, VertexCoordinates -> 
  Thread[VertexList[g] -> (# {1, -1} &) /@ GraphEmbedding[g]]]
```

With [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM), doing this is much simpler:

```
IGVertexMap[{1, -1} # &, VertexCoordinates, g]
```

Personally, I do not do anything with graphs without IGraph/M ;-) IGraph/M also has a tree-drawing function, which happens to rotate the layout into a horizontal orientation differently.

```
IGLayoutReingoldTilford[g, "Rotation" -> Pi/2, "LayerHeight" -> 5]
```

Comment: Your `EdgeLabels` are all the same.  Should be `Map[First@# -> 
   Placed[InputForm[
     Last@#], {.7 , {.5, 
      0.75} }] &, edges]` instead.

Comment: @Edmund Thank you! I don't know how I could have not noticed that ...

Comment: seemed like a lot more work was needed to make the adjustments. A minor question, why are the ABC in `decending` order? I thought it was my machine, but it's all the same for any version of MMA....

Comment: I tried using `right` but it's like a mirror. I guess that's just the way it is then....

Comment: @CasperYC See update.